# How to draw a horizontal line at y=0 in an Altair line chart

Tags: python, altair

I'm creating a line chart using Altair. I have a DataFrame where my y-values move up and down around 0, and I'd like to add a phat line to mark y=0. Sounds easy enough, so I tried this:

```
# Add a horizontal line at y=0 to clearly distinguish between positive and negative values.
y_zero = alt.Chart().mark_rule().encode(
    y=alt.value(0),
    color=alt.value('black'),
    size=alt.value(10),
)
```

This indeed draws a horizontal line, but it gets drawn at the top very top of my chart. It seems Altair uses a coordinate system where (0,0) is at the top-left corner. How do I move my line to my data's y=0 position?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this maybe? ```y_zero = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y':[0]})).mark_rule(color='black', size=10).encode(y='y')```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Since it works I posted it as an answer. It'll kind of you if you upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `alt.datum` instead of `alt.value` will draw the line at the data value 0, instead at a pixel value of 0. You can read more and see examples in the docs here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/encodings/index.html#datum-and-value

Comment: Ah, this is even more elegant. There is a Altair native feature for what I needed. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
y_zero = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'y':[0]})).mark_rule(color='black', size=10).encode(y='y')
```

Comment: This definitely works, thanks a lot for the quick help! I found @joelostblom's answer even more elegant.